# Woman blowing shofar vs. hearing from a man?

Tags: women, shofar

If a woman knows how to blow shofar, is there any more mitzvah in her hearing it from a man vs. doing it herself? (Is it different that the mitzvah is *lishmoa* vs. *al tekias*?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Shulchan Aruch [O”C 589:6](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.589.6?lang=bi) says she can blow herself

> אף על פי שנשים פטורות יכולות לתקוע וכן אחר שיצא כבר יכול לתקוע להוציאן אבל אין מברכות ולא יברכו להן: הגה והמנהג שהנשים מברכות על מצות עשה שהזמן גרמא ע"כ גם כאן מברכות לעצמן אבל אחרים לא יברכו להן אם כבר יצאו

However there is a Shaagas Aryeh [Teshuva 104](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1832&st=&pgnum=170&hilite=) where he asks this exact question, which is better for a woman to do, and he says that it is better for a man to blow for her. His reasoning is that blowing shofar is generally prohibited on Yom Tov and is only permitted on Rosh Hashana for a man not a woman.

Comment: Why are only men permitted?

Comment: Because they have a mitzvah, while women are patur